# How to encode password in a python code script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to encode password in python script so no one can see it . I tried using keyring library to do this , but I'm not able to find a way to encode a password in a script itself . Below is my code

```
import keyring
keyring.set_password("system", "username", "password")
a = keyring.get_password("system", "username")
print(a)
```

when I print a I'll get None, how am i supposed to use a decrypted password in a code ?
is there any other way to do this ?
I want to encrypt it in smtplib password

```
smtp.login("username",a)
```

Comment: If you run your code just like that, you will get `password` in return.
Unless you run keyring.delete_password("system", "username") , you will always get `password` in return.

Comment: He, thanks for response , i know that it'll return response of a password but how can I pass that response to smtp login password, i should use decrypted string of password only @lalam

Comment: your code is correct,  because if you do `print(type(a))` , you will get `<class 'str'>` 
which is valid for your login `smtp.login("username",a)` .
If you're using that code inside a big function, you can test login with something like : `smtp.login("username",keyring.get_password("system", "username"))` 
to test that it works.

Comment: when I print type(a) Iam getting  <class 'NoneType'>  in linux , when I do keyring.get_password("system", "username") I get nothing.

Comment: Now the None return is definitely linked to the scope of keyring.
According to their official PyPI page :
`get_password(service, username): Returns the password stored in the active keyring. If the password does not exist, it will return None.` 
-Are you using a virtualenv ?
-Can you (for testing) run with `("system1", "username1")` ?

Comment: There is no safe way to store a password within source code! If someone has access to source code, and the code has access to a password (even if it is encrypted!), then the person who has access to the code also has access to the password.

Comment: he thanks for the reply, I just don't want to specify the password in the code, fine if it can be accessed @zvone

Comment: yes , I'm using it in virtual env , still it returns none with system1 @lalam

Comment: ok, as I am reading thtough their doc, they seem to have a way to set a custom keyring backend. Now if you run  `keyring.get_keyring()` 
by default you should see something like :
`<keyring.backends.SecretService.Keyring object at 0xSomeHex>` 

The idea is, to make sure the user/app running this code ,can actually retrieve the password stored in the keychain.

Comment: ok it definitely have to do with that background, here's 2 chunks from their source code :
on chainer.py :

`def get_password(self, service, username):
        for keyring in self.backends:
            password = keyring.get_password(service, username)
            if password is not None:
                return password`
on core.py :

`def get_password(service_name, username):
    """Get password from the specified service.
    """
    return _keyring_backend.get_password(service_name, username)`
I think the backend somewhat defines the access scope to the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in module in Python called `hashlib`. You can use it like this:

```
import hashlib

hashlib.md5(username.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Keep in mind that MD5 algorithm is not secure, you should use something like SHA256.

View documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hashlib.html)